# All the cities and their state codes

Tags: data-request

I need for my database a list of all the cites, countries and states in the world. 
If I'm looking for Albany in this list, I need it to be like this:
USA, NY, Albany
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of United States cities](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6800/list-of-united-states-cities)

Comment: Not duplicate: he is considering all world, not just USA.